# How do I have to define a Pattern in Jackson to deserialize it

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I'm having problems googling this or finding the documentation for it. It seems that jackson knows how to deserialize a `Pattern` class, at least it's not complaining about it on my class that I'm deserialing to, but how do I define said object in my `yaml`/`json`/`xml`? will it only work for a string? or can it take flags too? or do I need to do custom deserialization to do flags?

Comment: Does this answer your question @xenoterracide ?

Comment: @YassinHajaj yeah, I think well enough

Comment: Alright good luck :)